# Launching user program on Windows Server from C# Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, process, windows-server

I am working on a ASP.NET web service that'll run on a AWS EC2 Windows Server instance. What it will do is receive some files and start a process (Marmoset Toolbag, a 3D tool) with some arguments. This program converts files to another format and closes afterwards. The code that runs the process:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
            {                    
                p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = _args;
                bool result = p.Start();
                int timeOut = 15000;
                int intInterval = 100;
                while (!p.HasExited)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(intInterval);
                    timeOut -= intInterval;
                    if (timeOut <= 0) break;
                }
                if (timeOut <= 0)
                {
                    //timeout happened
                    p.Kill();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AddToRespondBody(CustomResponse.Conversion_failed, false, e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
```

This all works fine locally in debug mode.
But when I run this on IIS on the server instance, the process does open but is in background and stays idle. 
After some research I found some information that this doesn't really work on server because of permission problems:

> ASP.NET Web page and server control code executes in the context of the ASP.NET worker process on the Web server. If you use the Start method in an ASP.NET Web page or server control, the new process executes on the Web server with restricted permissions. The process does not start in the same context as the client browser, and does not have access to the user desktop.

I also tried a way with `ProcessStartInfo` but again without success. If I understand this problem correctly I need to run the process with higher priviliges, but even this didn't help. Is there even a way to pull this off with running a user program from a process?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you find out what rights exactly are needed by this Software?

Comment: How can I do this? AFAIK it only needs read/write permission and the user window. I'm currently trying out a library for creating tasks, that seems to work on the server aswell: https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler

Comment: Well, what you can try is to start the Process with an impersonation ("as User X").